# Error burning DVD using Devede on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, ubuntu-9.04, burning

I'm trying to burn a DVD in DeVeDe under ubuntu --
on my computer it's already in DVD format (a VIDEO_TS folder) but when I try and drag it into DeVeDe it says "Some files weren't video files. None added."

From looking at it, all the files look like they belong there, just from doing this a few times already and seeing all the files contained in a DVD.

The file extensions in the folder are:

> VOB
>   BUP
>   IFO

and the files are all named like `VTS_02_1.VOB`.

I have tried excluding the IFO files when dragging them into DeVeDe but get the same error.

Is the problem in the types of files in the DVD data or is the DVD corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

DeVeDe is for authoring DVDs, making the `VIDEO_TS` contents from some arbitrary video sources.

If you just want to burn some files that are already in DVD-compliant format, use a plain old data burner such as Brasero or GnomeBaker.

Answer (score 0):

bobince is almost correct. Checkout the [devede-faq](http://files.majorsilence.com/devede/docs/faq.html):

#### I added a VOB file and marked the option "This is already a DVD/xCD-suitable MPEG file", but DeVeDe fails.

The VOB files aren't fully suitable for DVDAuthor. In order to get the right file you can repackage it (without recompressing, so you will not loose quality) just marking the option Repack audio and video without reencoding.